# Resolution stuck at 1024x768

Tags: xorg

In an attempt to fix some minor issues with the splash screen, I ran this script: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html

Big mistake. My resolution is now stuck at 1024x768 (the screen is 1280x900). I can't change it through the Monitors settings, and either there's lots of old guides out there or my Xorg config doesn't exist. I tried running the cleanup version of the "fix script" but nothing changed. Oh and the graphics settings are also at minimum all of a sudden.

I also tried all sorts of `dpkg --reconfigures`, no luck there either.

```
alexander@natty:~$ xrandr 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0
```

Comment: graphics card?  Are you running with any additional Graphics Drivers?  Please supply your current xorg.conf.  Please supply your current grub boot line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this script does:

1. In `/etc/default/grub`

   1. replace

      `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

      with

      `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option='$resolution',mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"`
   2. set GRUB_GFXMODE=$resolution
2. In `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

   1. add `uvesafb mode_option=$resolution mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap`
3. In `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash`

   1. add `FRAMEBUFFER=y`

Reverse whatever it actually did do, and do this:

```
 sudo update-grub2
 sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had done everything except removing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option='$resolution',mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap", and changing that fixed it.