# xubuntu boot hangs after "upgrade" to 18.04

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 18.04, intel

Frustration may make me short and sarcastic, please forgive.
Early this morning I attempted to "upgrade" from 16.04 to 18.04 on a Foxconn Product:Nettop nT-535.  On the post upgrade reboot, the splash screen "Xubuntu" shows a rotating circle segment that freezes and hangs for at least tens of minutes. Eventually something times out and the monitor shows "no signal."
I have been able to SSH to it and explore. I'm blaming the display first.

lshw identifies:
display:0
VGA compatible controller
Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller
...
driver=i915
After reading more about Intel VS Ubuntu than I ever, ever wanted to, I tried a package from the "Intel Open Source Technology Center."

intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_i386.deb 
without success.  The errors claim "dependency problems prevent configuration of intel-graphics-update-tool"
It said the tool depended on libpackagekit-glib2-16 which was unavailable; missing or obsoleted or only available from another source. (source unspecified.)
It seems libpackagekit-glib2-18 is appropriate for 18.04 but when I tried to install that, it said I already had libpackagekit-glib2-18 in the newest version and further down in that attempted install that intel-graphics-update-tool depended on libpackagekit-glib2-16 "but it is not installable"  Recommending "libproxyl-plugin-webkit" WTF do I do with that?

I've been using the device to monitor and upload security camera data from a private cabin.  It's now mid afternoon and I'm very tempted to throw the thing into the lake and let the fish worry about it.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: dhill4001 here---I threw it in the lake.    No, really, I haven't yet, but plan to back off to 16.04 in the belief that 18.04 doesn't have a driver for my nettop display.  So mark it SOLVED.... sort of.  For the task of camera monitoring, I drafted another machine.  BTW, What was "sudo apt install -f" supposed to do?

Comment: It resolves dependency issues

Comment: Maybe assess whether any of the answers for [GNOME-]Ubuntu are also applicable to Xubuntu - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030483/stuck-at-ubuntu-18-04-logo-while-booting-after-installing